# Adding properties to JHipster Cloud application.yml causes registry configuration to fail

Tags: java, spring, jhipster, jhipster-registry

I want to add a custom property to the `application.yml` of my Cloud Config. The comments in the file say it is for all shared configuration. However, when I do so, it causes the binding of the properties to JHipsters own ApplicationProperties to fail at the class does not have the correct writable property.

application.yml

```
application:
    clients:
        - Foo
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedBindingNotWritablePropertyException: Failed to bind 'application.clients[0]' from 'file:central-config/localhost-config/application.yml' to 'clients[0]' property on 'io.github.jhipster.registry.config.ApplicationProperties'
```

Answer (score 1):

From JHipster's documentation:

> Application-specific properties Your generated application can also
>   have its own Spring Boot properties. This is highly recommended, as it
>   allows type-safe configuration of the application, as well as
>   auto-completion and documentation within an IDE.
>
> JHipster has generated a ApplicationProperties class in the config
>   package, which is already preconfigured, and it is already documented
>   at the bottom the application.yml, application-dev.yml and
>   application-prod.yml files. *All you need to do is code your own
>   specific properties.* (emphasis mine)

Have you done that step and added your own properties to `ApplicationProperties.java`? It looks like you should have a property of type `List<String> clients`. If you haven't that's why it's failing, because it's attempting to bind a configuration property to the `ApplicationProperties` class, but the class doesn't contain a property to store it.

Comment: The problem is not with the ApplicationProperties of my project, it is the properties class within the Registry application. I startup the registry via docker, which uses this image: jhipster/jhipster-registry:v3.1.0. The ApplicationProperties within the application inside there is what breaks.

Comment: Well the problem is still the same. The `ApplicationProperties` (https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/registry/config/ApplicationProperties.java) in that project does not have a property called clients. So you cannot set a value in application.properties that does not exist there.

Comment: What exactly are you _trying_ to do by adding this client properties to the registry?

Answer (score 0):

Custom Spring boot properties should always be defined in a @ConfigurationProperties class within the app so that their value can be setup in the yml file. This is thoroughly documented in the spring boot documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: It's the ApplicationProperties within the JHipster registry itself which is breaking, not mine.

Comment: You should definitely have made it clear in your question that the error was in the registry ! Then this is normal as `central-config/application.yml` is loaded by all apps including the registry which configures itself. So you have to modify the ApplicationProperties file of the registry to add the `clients` property you added.